# A $\delta$- chain is $\delta$ shadowed by identity map

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Let $f$ be the identity map on the space $X=\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty} $, where  $x_i=\sum_{n=1}^i\frac{1}{n}$, given the metric inherited from $\mathbb{R}$. Also, let for finite sequence $\{y_n\}_{n=0}^m\subseteq X$, we have $|y_0-y_m|<\delta$ and  $|y_n-y_{n+1}|<\delta$ for $n=0, 1, \ldots m-1$.

Question. Is it true there is $z\in\{y_n\}_{n=0}^m$ such that $|z-y_n|<\delta$ for all $n=0, 1, \ldots, m$?

Comment: No, it is not true. You can go as far away as you want and then come back. Why do you think this should be true? Maybe you want to impose further conditions?

Comment: @S.Schraven. There is no further conditions. give an example please , if $\delta>0$ is sufficiently small

Comment: Only I can choice $z\in X$, hence

Comment: Is it true there is $z\in X$ such that $|z-y_n|<\delta$ for all $n=0, 1, \ldots, m$?

Answer (score 1):

Choose $\delta >0$ in any way you like. Pick $N>0$ sufficiently large s.t. $1/N<\delta$. Then consider the sequence $y_0=x_N=y_{2l}, \ y_1=x_{N+1}=y_{2l-1}, \dots, y_{l}=x_{N+l}$. Clearly $\vert y_0 -y_{2l} \vert =0<\delta$ and $\vert y_n - y_{n+1} \vert \leq 1/N <\delta $, but $\vert y_0  - y_l \vert = \sum_{k=N+1}^{N+l} 1/k$ which we can make as large as we want by making $l$ large.

Note that in fact there does not even exist $z\in X$ (i.e. if we are not forced to pick $z\in (y_m)_{m=0}^{2l})$ such that $\vert z  - y_m \vert<\delta$ for all $m=0, \dots , 2l$.